# Different behaviour of json.parse for same input?

Tags: javascript, json, string

This question is about

> why the outputs are different

not how can i achieve the proper output.

I am unable to understand why the output of following two scenarios is not the same, even if I am giving the same argument to the JSON.parse() function.

FIRST scenario

```
obj = {a:"asdf"};
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));     //newObj = {a:"asdf"}
```

Debugging
[image: Debugging view]

SECOND scenario

```
var newObj = JSON.parse("{"a":"asdf"}");        //this gives an error
```

Comment: The hint you get in your debugger brought you confusion. Even though there you see `"{"a":"asdf"}"` this is not a properly formatted string. If you start a string with " then you end it with ". Which means, here the string is only "{" and the rest is broken code the browser doesn't know what to do with. As said in answers you can either use ' to encapsulate the whole string as `'{"a":"asdf"}'` or you escape the inner " as `"{\"a\":\"asdf\"}"`.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but -- JSON.stringify(obj) - returns "{"a":"asdf"}" only, then how does it work in this case. --JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: It does not. The browser outputs it in the console as `"{"a":"asdf"}"` but it is actually returning a string that reads `{"a":"asdf"}`. The browser console decides to encapsulate this in a " because that is the default console behaviour with strings. So you will read `"{"a":"asdf"}"` but it is actually a type string with a value of `{"a":"asdf"}`.

Comment: But doing this -- JSON.parse({"a":"asdf"}) -- also gives an error.

Comment: Because the parameter you are passing to JSON.parse is an object, not a string. That is why you should do `JSON.parse('{"a":"asdf"}')`. Check my answer, I try to explain it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the outputs are different

Because the inputs are different.

FIRST scenario

```
obj = {a:"asdf"};
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Here the input parameter of `JSON.parse` is `JSON.stringify(obj)`and this is a string that reads `{"a":"asdf"}`.

SECOND scenario

```
var newObj = JSON.parse("{"a":"asdf"}");
```

Here the input parameter of `JSON.parse` is a string that reads `{` and the rest is broken code.

Confusion arises because the console debugger decides all strings should be shown on the console encapsulated with a `"`, but this is just a way for the console to tell you that this value is of type String. It does not check whether you have " inside and escape them.

The encapsulating `"` are not part of the string, only a way of telling it is a string.

If console.logging JSON.stringify(obj) gets you `"{"a":"asdf"}"` try doing alert instead, or document.write. These will not add extra `"` and you will see that the value of JSON.stringify(obj) is actually `{"a":"asdf"}`, not `"{"a":"asdf"}"`.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script>
function JSONparse(string) {
    document.write(string);
    alert(string);
    console.log(string);
    return JSON.parse(string);
}
var obj = {a:"asdf"};
result = JSONparse(JSON.stringify(obj));
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with quotes.

```
var newObj = JSON.parse('{"a":"asdf"}');
```

should work correctly.

In Javascript, we use quotes (single or double) to represent a String. When you want to define a String that contains quotes, then you must use different quotes, or `escape` the quotes using backslash `\` character.

```
var newObj = JSON.parse("{\"a\":\"asdf\"}");
```

also works fine.

You might think that

```
var newObj = JSON.parse("{'a':'asdf'}");
```

would work, but no. In JSON, strings are defined using Double quotes only.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but -- JSON.stringify(obj) - returns "{"a":"asdf"}" only, then how does it work in this case. --JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Answer (score 0):

```
var newObj = JSON.parse('{"a":"asdf"}');
```